# How to make the content of list (tree view data in list ul and li tags) expanded by default?

Tags: html, css, angular, treeview

I have an angular component with tree view data in list (ul and li tags).
I want the content of tree view expanded by default [at least first level should be expanded by default].

**I have the following code:**

**In Html**

```
<ul style="list-style: none; Isexpanded:true" >
        <li *ngFor="let contentNode of contentNodes" class="tree__branch" [ngClass]="{'tree__branch--has-children': contentNode.has_children}">
            <a *ngIf="contentNode.has_children" (click)="contentNode.toggle=!contentNode.toggle" class="toggle">{{ !!contentNode.toggle ? '▼' : '▶' }}</a> <a [routerLink]="['/loc-admin/locationView', contentNode.pk_location_id]"></a>{{ contentNode.locationname }}
          <content-list *ngIf="contentNode.toggle" [startingNode]="contentNode.pk_location_id"  [myData]="rows"></content-list>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**In component.ts**

```
export class ContentListComponent implements OnInit {

constructor (private _contentService: LocationService) {}

errorMessage: string;

@Input('startingNode')
private _startNodeId: string;

@Input('myData')
private _myData = [];

rows=[];

contentNodes: Location[];
bookFilteredList : Location[];


ngOnInit() { 
    this.rows=this._myData;
    this.contentNodes=this.rows;
    //console.dir(this.contentNodes);
    //this.getContentNodes();
    this.filter();
}

filter(){
    //console.log('Excecute filter');
    let storageId = this._startNodeId;

    this.bookFilteredList = this.contentNodes.filter((book: Location) => book.parent_location_id === storageId);
    this.contentNodes = this.bookFilteredList;
    console.log(this.bookFilteredList);
    return this.contentNodes;
}   

// getContentNodes() {
//  this._contentService.getChildLocations(this._startNodeId)
//      .subscribe(
//          contentNodes => this.contentNodes = contentNodes,
//          error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error

//      );
//      console.dir(this.contentNodes)
// }

toggleBranch(branchId:number){
    console.log('branchId: ' + branchId);
}
```

}

If I remove  ***ngIf="contentNode.toggle"** from the following line, I am getting tree view in uncollapsible format, but then the toggle is not working.

```
<content-list *ngIf="contentNode.toggle" [startingNode]="contentNode.pk_location_id"  [myData]="rows"></content-list>
            </li>
```

Can any one give me the solution?

Thanks & Regards

Shilpa Kulkarni

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for my issue.

The value of contentNode.toggle is false and hence  is not generated and I was getting list in collapsible format. I made it true by using (!) sign as *ngIf="!contentNode.toggle".

Tried as follows and getting the content of tree view expanded by default:

```
 <content-list *ngIf="!contentNode.toggle" [startingNode]="contentNode.pk_location_id"  [myData]="rows"></content-list>
```